# Generator of a kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

"For a $V$ finite-dimensional, the homomorphism

$f: k[x] \rightarrow k[T] \subset End_k(V)$ by $x \rightarrow T$ where $T$ is an endomorphism from  $V \rightarrow V$ and $k$ is a ring.

$f$ must have a non-trivial kernel, since $k[x]$ is infinite-dimensional but $k[T]$ is finite-dimensional. The minimal polynomial $g(x) \in k[x]$ of $T$ is the monic generator of that kernel."

That last bit is causing me some confusion. Is it saying that $g(x)$ generates the entire kernel of $f$? And if so, how? $k[x]$ is not a principal ideal domain, so how can we describe the kernel with a single generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a field $k$ the polynomial ring $k[x]$ is a principal ideal domain. In fact it's a Euclidean domain. We take the monic generator to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: oops, yeah. I think I assumed $k$ was a ring instead of a field since it was called a polynomial ring. Makes much more sense - thanks a lot